# Google Recaptcha verification ajax and Php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-modal, recaptcha

I am trying to implement on Google recaptcha v2 for Javascript Modal and form on same page. I am having issue with verification issue. Here, my ajax call and php code. I am unable to figure about the code recaptcha verification goes in PHP. I had review stack overflow answers, but unable to resolve my issue.

Here's my `index.php` code and doing ajax call.

```
<script>
$("#Maincontact").validate({
            rules: {
                inputbox: "required",
                firstname: { required: true,},
                lastname: { required: true,},
                email: {    required: true,
                            email: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    phonenumber: true
                },
            },`
            `messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your first name",
                lastname: "Please enter your last name",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                phone: "Please enter a valid phone number"
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "form-error",
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) { },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var firstname       = $('#firstname1').val();
                var lastname        = $('#lastname1').val();
                var message         = $('#message').val();
                var email           = $('#email1').val();
                var phone           = $('#phone1').val();
                var gcaptchaVal = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
var jqxhr = $.post( "mail_send.php", { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname,email: email,phone: phone,message: message, gcaptcha1: gcaptchaVal }, function(data) {
                if(data == '1'){
                    $('#recaptcha2').html('Captcha successfully');
                    $('#emailAlert1').addClass('green');
                    $('.formItems-body').hide();
                    $('#emailAlert1').html('Message sent successfully');
                } else {//alert('hie');die;
                    $('#emailAlert1').removeClass('green');
                    $('#emailAlert1').html(data);
                    $('#recaptcha2').html('Please Fill recaptcha');
                }
                }).done(function(data) {
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    alert( "An error occured. Please try again" );
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here's my form:

```
<form action="/mail-send" method="post" name="contactForm" id="Maincontact">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-bodyInn">`
        <span id="emailAlert1"></span>
            <div class="box-contactField formItems-body">
                <div class="row-contactField">
                    <div class="col-contactField6">
                       <input class="input-contact required" type="text" title="First Name" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" id="firstname1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-contactField6">
                       <input class="input-contact required" type="text" title="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" id="lastname1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row-contactField">
                <div class="col-contactField12">
                   <input class="input-contact required" type="text" title="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email1"/>
                </div>
            </div>                  
         <div class="row-contactField">
            <div class="col-contactField6">
                <input class="input-contact required" type="text" title="Phone Number" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone1"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-contactField">
         <div class="col-contactField12">
            <textarea class="textarea-contact required" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha2" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-send"><input class="input-sendContact" type="submit" title="SEND" value="SEND" id="emailSubmit"/>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

And I have three google recaptcha on same page:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  `var verifyCallback = function(response) {
    alert(response);
  };

  var widgetId1;
  var widgetId2;
  var widgetId3;

  var onloadCallback = function() {
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
         widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
        widgetId3 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha3', {
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
      };

</script>
```

I have issue in verification. Thank You

Comment: I only see the frontend part and not the server side validation https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: I am not able to figure it out, where the server side code goes in send_mail.php and I have tried couple of things. But, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts in the reCaptcha implementation, the frontend part and the backend part, you have already implemented the frontend, after this in your server you have to validate with the google service that response is valid.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$postfields = array(
  'secret' => '[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]', //This is different to your sitekey
  'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
);

$options = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postfields),
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

if($response['success']){
    //pass the reCaptcha Validation
}
```

Comment: Great, I have done the backend part. it's issue with form validation Jquery. $("#Maincontact").validate is not validating Google recaptcha response before submit the form. Thanks for your help Jose Rojas!

Comment: @Nisarg if my answer help you to solve your issue, could you accept my answer?